# Swagger-ui keeps showing example petstore instead of provided swagger.json

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I followed instructions to set up swagger documentation for my existing node API using swagger-jsdoc.
The swagger.json is being served correctly and I added a path to it in the url parameter of the SwaggerUiBundle in index.html like this:

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
url: "https://my.domain:5292/swagger.json",
dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
presets: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
  SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
],
plugins: [
  SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
],
layout: "StandaloneLayout" })
```

However, the first thing it tries to do when opening the page in the browser is showing the default *http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json* instead of my *swagger.json*. It actually fails to do so because I'm serving the page through https and the petstore is not https but that's a different matter...

Inputing my address to the *swagger.json* manually into the form on the page works as expected. It shows the API page correctly and validates it. However, I don't want to always re-enter the address there and would like to have it as a default.

Answer (score 3):

Swagger UI 3.0.9 had a [bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3045) where it ignored the `url` parameter and always opened Petstore.

It was fixed in 3.0.10.

Comment: Hah, I knew it would be something like this. I'm not actually going to check this because I moved away from swagger in the end but this looks like perfect explanation. Thanks.

Comment: I had this issue recently and I have to say you much update your swagger version to the last version that has been released

Answer (score 2):

I had been having this issue lately when deploying using docker. Tried everything from changing all instance of petstore to my own api json docs but to no avail.
Finally I found out about API_URL environment variable, set it to my api docs in DockerFile and voila!
Took me two days but it was great to see it finally working.

Comment: Hi GANI first of all I am using Swagger UI 3.25.0
In the dockerfile I add the following line
ENV API_KEY "**None**"
ENV SWAGGER_JSON "/app/swagger.json"
ENV PORT 8080
**ENV API_URL "https://mycustomurl.com/swagger/docs/v1"**

Answer (score 1):

You can disabled default url by adding below configuration in application.property file

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
```